# Convert SHA-512 hashing from Java to Bash

Tags: java, bash, sha512

I have a big code in Java that hashes a string using SHA-512, and I've been unable to get similar results in Bash. So I decided to simplify it the most I was able to hunt for the problem, and came up with this small piece of code:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

class Test {
  public static void main(String []args) throws Exception {
    String SECRET = "secret";
    String STRING = "string";
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
    digest.update(SECRET.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] d = digest.digest(STRING.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, d).toString(16));
  }
}
```

which returns:

```
26620758babadb008ee7b98e1bb07351f08d49228c15f6f31c4ee75cb9a26f5079b81c01f14f78cf5f9639e49d7319ee3c3fcc1f94e686b8d605c93f2ab9fb4
```

From my understanding, this would be equivalent to:

```
#!/bin/bash

SECRET="secret"
STRING="string"

echo -n "$STRING" | openssl sha512 -hmac "$SECRET"
```

but this returns:

```
c13223b6f7331a608ec24bf3adfd8f599622b4d5b28cd27f9dcf92430a6263f435d07ff59809785ef04c5cb4aefd02357578efc8862e254a7505e26c76806194
```

The only thing I have noticed is that if I change the value of `toString(16)`, the result changes too. But from reading [its documentation](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_tostring.htm), I could not figure out what it does!

Comment: HMAC is NOT just hashing key+data, you must hash twice (to prevent MD extension attacks) with different padding, see http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104 .

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK, thank you! But in this case I was actually trying to authenticate with an API.

Comment: Okay, then reverse it :-) HMAC is not just hash(key+data). If you want just hash(key+data) as you apparently do, don't use HMAC.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 OK, got it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

> ```
> echo -n "secretstring" | sha512sum -
> ```

I get

026620758babadb008ee7b98e1bb07351f08d49228c15f6f31c4ee75cb9a26f5079b81c01f14f78cf5f9639e49d7319ee3c3fcc1f94e686b8d605c93f2ab9fb4  -

(there is a leading zero). The issue with your command is the argument `-hmac`. It works here with

> ```
> echo -n "secretstring" | openssl sha512
> ```

Output of

(stdin)= 026620758babadb008ee7b98e1bb07351f08d49228c15f6f31c4ee75cb9a26f5079b81c01f14f78cf5f9639e49d7319ee3c3fcc1f94e686b8d605c93f2ab9fb4

Finally, changing the value you pass to `toString()` changes the number's radix (or base).